# How to get the TResult of Func in C#?

Tags: c#

I am new to func, I have define the `Func` like below,

```
 private Func<int, Type, GridCell> getGridCell;
 public Func<int, Type, GridCell> GetGridCell
  {
    get
     {
       return getGridCell;
     }
   set
    {
      getGridCell = value;
    }
  }
```

And I don't know how to get the TResult that is GridCell.
Could you please suggest on this?

Comment: Your example does not illustrate the stated problem. The result type is known here because it is explicitly defined right here. Can you post your code which suffers from lack of result type knowledge?

Comment: Where exactly you are facing the problem? Where are you expecting TResult?

Comment: You encapsulated getGridCell of the Func<int, Type, GridCell> so whenever you access GetGridCell you are getting the definition of the function and not the result of it which is supposed to return an object of type GridCell. Better refer to tutorials on defining Func.

Comment: @Farjanaparveen Guess you just want to execute you `Func` `obj.GetGridCell(someInt, someType)`.

Comment: I have added the below code to call the func
GridCell gridcell = this.DataGrid.GetGridCell(dataColumn.RowIndex, typeof(GridCell));
 
and create the method like below

   public GridCell GetCustomGridCell(int rowindex, Type type)
        {
          return new CustomGridCell();
        } 

In button click i try to get the GridCell

 private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var data = this.sfdatagrid.GetGridCell;
        }
i don't know how to get

Comment: if you want answers to your problem then please check how to ask question FAQ....Edit your question with proper code.....

Answer (score 7):

A `Func` doesn't have a result until you call it. So `GetGridCell` doesn't have a value of type `GridCell` - it's a function which can be *called* to get a `GridCell`. For example:

```
Func<int, Type, GridCell> function = GetGridCell;
GridCell cell1 = function(1, typeof(string));
GridCell cell2 = function(10, typeof(DateTime));
```

How exactly that is computed depends on the value of `GetGridCell` - it could do anything, basically, because it's just a function.

Note that this isn't specific to `Func` types - it's the general idea of delegates.

Comment: Hi Jon,                                                                                                                                          Thank you for your answer. I have call the func, by using the below code            GridCell gridcell = this.DataGrid.GetGridCell(dataColumn.RowIndex, typeof(GridCell));